# What is the best way to start using git with for wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, github, server

What would be the best solution? Connect the server to the Git or use a WordPress any tested plugin to sync with Git?

For reference, I have wordpress website. I use SiteGround for server. In WP Plugins I use Divi Builder.

Answer (score 2):

You can add all necessary code on the git, for example, your plugin files, themes, etc. exclude upload folders, the config files, add those in gitignore. And use Jenkins for deployment to the server.

Comment: So, which plugin do you recommend for syncing WordPress and Git?

Comment: I don't use any plugins, I'm using the terminal for git commit, push, pull, etc. and this is so simple you can find tons of git basic command articles. Even you can use git UI for all basic operations and all smart IDE for example phpstorm, vscode, the sublime text has git functionality and support all necessary git commands.

Comment: So, you connect Git to the server and not to WordPress. Did I understand correctly?